# Irritating auto brightness adjustment

Tags: windows-8, brightness, contrast

I have a new windows 8 that when looking at dark colors, the screen will dim.
I've turned off adaptive brightness, checked the Intel graphics and media control panel and NOTHING helped. This stupid sh*tty "feature" is getting really annoying. How do you get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

You're turned off adaptive brightness ? 
So what do you have Laptop or Desktop PC ? 
Maybe you have some kind of Light Sensor that changes you display brightness, and maybe is not working properly :) You sould set him off ...

Answer (score 0):

This most likely sounds like you have an adaptive brightness sensor on your screen itself. I have had this exact problem with using TVs as monitors for conference room setups. I have a SHARP LCD television screen that has an 'Eco' auto-brightness adjust.

To stop this from happening you need to use your remote to enter into the menus on the TV and turn off the adaptive brightness setting.